# Children-friendly beaches in Los Angeles, Southern California, USA

Tags: children, beaches, los-angeles, southern-california

We plan to visit Los Angeles with young children (age 2 and 5) in the summer.

I have been to Los Angeles before and am quite familiar with the beaches there (eg Venice Beach, Santa Monica pier).  But almost all the beaches I know of have seas that are cold and rough with waves.  In other words, unsafe for young children to wade in and play. This is understandable because the sea of California is the Pacific Ocean, unlike the closed seas of the Mediterranean or the Caribbean.

Are there any beaches near LA or in the greater Southern California area that are sheltered, that is, within an inlet, cove, small bay, so that the water is calm and gentle and preferably shallow near the edges so it's safe for young children to play in?

I would also expand this search to include beaches on lakes too as long as it has soft surface (eg sandy) and it's children-friendly and shallow near the edges.

Comment: [LMGTFY](https://mommypoppins.com/kids/easy-beach-destinations-10-great-beaches-for-kids-in-la-and-oc)

Answer (score 4):

Credits to @Dorothy for the link to [kid-friendly beaches in OC and LA.](https://mommypoppins.com/kids/easy-beach-destinations-10-great-beaches-for-kids-in-la-and-oc)

[Best Beaches for Kids and Families in Los Angeles & Orange County
6/3/13 - By Martha Hall](https://mommypoppins.com/kids/easy-beach-destinations-10-great-beaches-for-kids-in-la-and-oc)
>

> **Malibu**
>   Leo Carrillo State Beach
>   35000 West Pacific Coast Highway
>   Malibu, CA 90265
>   310.457.8143
>
> A classic family beach spot, and it's no wonder. With easy parking, a "tunnel" that walks you under the PCH to the beach (that alone is exciting), and plenty of sand and tidepools once you get there, this destination is a repeat favorite. Don't forget to explore the rocks and caves, too! You can even make a weekend of it at the nearby campground.
>
> **Paradise Cove**
>   28128 Pacific Coast Highway
>   Malibu, CA 90265
>   310.457.2503
>   Parking: $40/day (or $6 for up to 4 hours with meal purchase)
>
> Feel like splurging? No, we mean really splurging. Then make a day of it at Paradise Cove. It's a private beach, and there's no surfing allowed, so the rolling waves are just for the swimmers. Many a movie and TV show were filmed here (Baywatch, Gidget, Sponge Bob Square Pants: The Movie) so the backdrop may look familiar. Rent a beach chair, rent an umbrella, or occupy your own little hut. No luxury is spared (including valet parking at no extra charge!). Grab some lunch at the Beach Cafe (a $30 purchase cuts the parking rate to $6 for 4 hours). It's all there for you and your little gang.
>
> **Zuma Beach**
>   30000 Pacific Coast Highway
>   Malibu, CA 90265
>   310.457.9701
>   Parking: $3-$10
>
> Sure it gets crowded in the summer, but that's because beach goers know a good thing when they see it. Picturesque, secluded, with a familiar rock face you may recognize from a movie or two, Zuma Beach is just that beach you want to plop down on for the day. The little ones can glide on their boogie boards, build a sand castle or two, and watch the daring rock climbers.
>
> **Santa Monica Bay**
>   Annenberg Community Beach House
>   415 Pacific Coast Highway
>   Santa Monica, CA 90402
>   310.458.4904
>   Parking: $3/hour, $12/day
>
> A personal favorite because, really, what's not to like? You get the double delight of both a pool ($10) with beach house (read: clean bathrooms and indoor showers), splash pad, and a wide beach just steps away. Plus there's a snack bar and a playground. Final bonus: the boardwalk down to the shore makes it easy to bring a stroller.
>
> **Playa Del Rey Beach**
>   Culver Blvd. & Pacific Ave.
>   Playa del Rey, CA 90293
>   Free parking
>
> Want a simple no-frills beach with free parking? Head west on Culver Blvd. until it dead-ends at the ocean, and there you have it. The Del Rey Lagoon is just across the street, complete with playground and wetland birds (and BBQs on the grass). Stop off at Tanner's Coffee for java and a treat.
>
> **Redondo Beach Pier**
>   100 W. Torrance Blvd.
>   Redondo Beach, CA 90277
>   Parking: $3-$7.50
>
> Okay, this is not one of those cozy, tucked away beaches where civilization recedes into the background. But if you and the kids are in the mood for beach with commotion and activity, check out Redondo Beach. Just steps from the Pier, is the beach, and (of course) just steps from the beach, is the Pier, bustling with ice cream shops, kite shops, restaurants, and pterodactyl-like pelicans swooping down for a rest.
>
> **Palos Verdes and Long Beach**
>
> **Abalone Cove**
>   5970 Palos Verdes Dr. S
>   Palos Verdes, CA 90275
>   310.377.1222
>   Parking: $5
>
> This beach is fabulous, but (disclaimer) it involves a lengthy walk down a trail to get there. If your little troopers can keep their eye on the prize, rewarded they will be. Sand, surf, and bountiful tidepools (with plenty of star fish), plus more trails to explore if the spirit moves. Grassy lawns and picnic tables abound near the parking lot for a post-beach picnic.
>
> **Cabrillo Beach**
>   3720 Stephen M. White Dr.
>   San Pedro, CA 90731
>   310.548.2909
>   Parking: $1/hour, $9 max. in the lot, or look for nearby free street parking.
>
> Here's another beach with more than just sand a surf. Check out the tide pools, as well as nearby Cabrillo Marine Aquarium for a well-rounded outing. There are two beach options: one with larger waves beyond the breakwater, and one in the harbor with gentler wave action, both within the same walking vicinity.
>
> **Orange County**
>
> **Little Corona Del Mar Beach**
>   Ocean Blvd. & Poppy Ave.
>   Corona del Mar, CA 92625
>   949.644.3309
>   Free street parking
>
> Hands down, one of the better beaches to hit with kids in tow. Park for free in the nearby neighborhood, take a short walk down a ramp, and you arrive at a little oasis where it's easy to watch the kids, the tide is gentle, and hermit crabs shuffle through the tide pools. Restrooms and showers are also available.
>
> **Baby Beach in Dana Point Harbor**
>   Dana Point Harbor
>   34551 Puerto Place
>   Dana Point, CA 92629
>   Free parking for first 4 hours
>
> The name of this beach about says it all. Babies (and toddlers and those a bit bigger) can frolic in the calm waters of this little cove. Showers and bathrooms are available. The only note of caution: it often gets crowded on weekends. But also on the weekends, the nearby Ocean Institute is open to the public.

Comment: I added the content so that your brief, link-only 'answer' didn't get deleted.